# handling button in prototype cell in tableview in swift 2

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, swift2

I can't find how to handle button in tableview. Ok, I have tableview which is display with some value like 100 Coins, 50 Coins ... and right side there is button. So question is when you press that button how does that button know that you have tapped button of specific value? Can some post place and code.

That button should perform message for buying products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one method in your controller i.e

```
func btnClickAction(sender: UIButton)
{
    var superView = sender.superview

    while superView?.isKindOfClass(UITableViewCell) == false
    {
        superView = superView?.superview
    }

    var cell = superView as! UITableViewCell
    var indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)! as NSIndexPath
}
```

From `indexPath` of above method you will find in which cell of button you were clicked.

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you need to add target of your button to above methods i.e

```
btn.addTarget(self, action: "btnClickAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDragInside)
```

Comment: Thank you for post. I dont know why people game -2 for question

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of late but I really like this solution so I hope it helps someone! This is @Jatin Chauhan 's answer but updated.

**Swift 3**

```
@IBAction func actionFromButtonPress(_ sender: Any) {

    var superView = (sender as AnyObject).superview

    while type(of: (superView!)!) != UITableViewCell.self
    {
        superView = (superView as AnyObject).superview
    }

    let cell = superView as! UITableViewCell
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)! as NSIndexPath
    let correspondingDataInDataSource = self.tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row]

        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Using this you can connect a button from your xib or storyboard to the IBAction here.

NOTE: If you have a custom UITableViewCell like I did you should not compare the type to be "UITableViewCell.self" but *instead* to "YourCustomTableViewCellClass.self".

NOTE 2: Notice that for the while loop I needed to unwrap twice. When I printed it out it was an optional optional and this way by unwrapping it the types can correctly compare against eachother.